# How to run batch script in IBM Rhapsody after build is successful to copy config files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rhapsody

I'm using IBM Rhapsody 7.4 with VS 2008 and I'd like to run custom batch script after the build is successful.

I've tried several options under Component ->Features->Properties but none worked. The latest one I tried was CG ->File->InvokePostProcessor  with something like $test.bat.

Any help or suggestion would be beneficial for me.

Thanks